# Pycrypto aes 256  Initialization vector size

Tags: python, google-app-engine, aes, pycrypto

here's the case i have a php script that's using aes256 ,CBC 
the both key and IV size are 32 bytes long

```
data= '123456789abcdef' 
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
a = AES.new('oqufXQ(?bc=6_hR2I3sMZChDpb6dDlw4',2,'fOaiIOkD8*9Xeu_s4_bb87Ox_UG+D9GA')
print a.encrypt(data)
```

and the error i got

```
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: IV must be 16 bytes long
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xxxxxxx/1.155074369696961822/main.py", line 4, in <module>
```

php code that works

```
 echo base64_encode(encrypt('0123456789abcdef'))  ;


 function encrypt($data)
  {
    return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 ,'oqufXQ(?bc=6_hR2I3sMZChDpb6dDlw4', $data , MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, utf8_encode('fOaiIOkD8*9Xeu_s4_bb87Ox_UG+D9GA') );
  }
```

I cant change the IV size

Note that I am Not very Familiar With Python,  Just Need a way to encrypt data as  it will be one appengine .

Comment: You can't not change the IV size. AES 256 is a block cipher with block size 16, so when used in any of the standard cipher modes that uses an IV, the IV is one block big, i.e. 16 bytes.

Comment: my php script is using a 32 bytes of random string as IV , am i doing something wrong? mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC); returns 32

Comment: Sorry, I don't know then. I would expect AES256 in CBC mode to use one block of IV, which is XORed with the first block of plaintext prior to encrypting that plaintext. If mcrypt does something different that involves another 16 bytes of IV, then it's not using the CBC cipher mode as *I* understand it, which means it's not going to inter-operate with an implementation that works the way I understand it. I don't claim that my understanding is any big deal, but it matches the error message you're getting from pycrypto, so I think that the cipher modes somehow aren't matched up.

Comment: Oh, I suppose one thing to check is whether mcrypt is using pbkdf2 or something to manipulate the so-called IV you give it, and using part of the result of that as the real IV.

Comment: added the php code that encrypts fine,  i don't think its uses pbkdf2 to derive new IV, not sure if php do that by default

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aha!

There's a difference of opinion what the "256" refers to.

AES has a fixed block size of 128 bits, so "AES 256" means 128 bit blocks, 256 bit *key*, 14 rounds.

However, Rijndael allows both the key size and the block size to vary. `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` refers to Rijndael with *block size* set to 256 (and I don't know how many rounds). So it does indeed take a 32 byte IV. Your PHP script is *not* using AES 256.

This is confirmed in https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47125 -- the reporter considers it a bug in PHP mcrypt, PHP considers it a bug in libmcrypt, but it's not a bug, since libmcrypt does document what `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` means (at least the linux man page for mcrypt does, my Google-fu has failed to find any actual documentation for libmcrypt). That thing happens not to be the same as what AES 256 means.

So, you're encrypting and decrypting with ciphers that although related, might as well be completely different.

The bad news is that there doesn't appear to be a `Crypto.Cipher.RIJNDAEL` in PyCrypto. If you can pass a 256-bit key to MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 in the PHP script, then that would be AES 256 (thanks Paŭlo).

Comment: @user80287. AES 128, 192 and 256 are three specific ways of configuring Rijndael. However, Rijndael has more configuration options than those. So if you have a complete Rijndael implementation then you easily do AES, but implementers don't necessarily write a fully-flexible Rijndael, they might cut it down just to the bits they need. So an AES implementation won't necessarily support block sizes other than 128.

Comment: Wow! Thanks For the explanation. I thought AES and Rijndael has a same implementation , I dont have control over the keys or IV i mean i cant change the IV. so I need to use other lib , thanks again.

Comment: @user80287, Steve: Actually, MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 ("Rijndael with 128 bit block size") is all three versions of AES - just pass a key of the right size, and it will choose the right algorithm (AES-128, AES-192, AES-256). (This will not help if you can't change the PHP script, though.)